# Using Ehcache to cache objects from Amazon S3

Tags: java, amazon-s3, ehcache

I have a huge number of objects on Amazon S3, of which only a small subset are accessed regularly. Thus, I'd really like to make use of a distributed caching system, like Ehcache. (Note, I'd use Cloudfront, but the data needs to be accessed from an API server, not from an enduser, and the Cloudfront does not support authentication last time I checked.)

Can anyone tell me whether or not this is feasible, practical, or whether or not there exists a library or example of using Ehcache to cache objects from Amazon S3?

Naturally, my app server is implemented in Java and is running on a Linux environment.

Thanks much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using [JetS3t](http://www.jets3t.org/) to read files from S3 and store them in a distributed ehcache cluster. The approach works quite well so far, although I find that JetS3t creates a [large number of temporary files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10391267/jets3t-fills-up-my-tmp-directory-how-should-i-remove-the-old-files) that have to be dealt with.

Answer (score 1):

Interesting idea - However, before diving into it eventually, I'd like to stress that authentication is available in [Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.amazon.com/cloudfront/) since September 2009, albeit likely not as you envision it, i.e. you can use [a Signed URL to Serve Private Content](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html):

> You can distribute private content with a static signed URL or a
>   dynamic signed URL. You use a static signed URL when distributing
>   private content to a known end user [...].
>   In this case, you create a signed URL and make the URL available to
>   your end users as needed. You use a dynamic signed URL to distribute
>   content on-the-fly to an end user for a limited purpose [...]
>   In this case, your application generates the signed URL.

This is further detailed in the [Overview of Private Content](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContentOverview.html):

> A CloudFront private distribution is based on a policy statement that
>   specifies any or all of the following constraints:
>
> - A start date that specifies the date and time the signed URL will be valid
> - An end date and time after which the signed URL will not be valid
> - **An IP address or range of IP addresses from which the signed URL can be used**
>
> *[emphasis mine]*

Whether this approach is feasible for your use case depends on the architecture of your solution, insofar you'll need to generate these signed URLs by some means and use those from the API server in turn; given your 'end user' is the API server, you might pre generate static URLs as suggested, on the other hand the most obvious approach might be to perform the signed URL generation process dynamically in the API server itself and cache the generated *URL<->Signed URL* map for reuse eventually (i.e. via Memcached or Ehcache indeed).

This authentication scheme is obviously more cumbersome than simple HTTP authentication for example, on the other hand it provides more flexibility as well, see e.g. the tutorial [Restricting Access to Files in a CloudFront Distribution Based on Geographic Location (Geoblocking)](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/RestrictingCFDistributionsByLocation.html) for an advanced use case, which is summarized in a [Guest Post: Geo-Blocking Content With Amazon CloudFront](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/01/guest-post-geo-blocking-content-with-amazon-cloudfront.html) on the AWS blog as well.

Comment: Thanks so much for the thorough answer. I'll take a look into this info.