# JetS3t fills up my /tmp directory. How should I remove the old files?

Tags: java, linux, amazon-s3, jets3t

I'm developing some HTTP server software on Linux that uses JetS3t to retrieve files from S3. The files are all around 5MB. Over time, JetS3t creates a large number of *.tmp files in the /tmp directory.

However, since this is all running on a server that is never rebooted, the files never get thrown away. Instead, they eventually fill up the root partition, causing a number of problems (like dropped HTTP connections, etc.)

Is there a way to configure JetS3t in a way that causes it to clean up after itself?

Thanks!

Comment: For those who vote to close: I don't think this belongs on ServerFault, because it's a JetS3t question, and I'm sure plenty of folks who use S3 with Java are using that framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I came up with an inelegant, but working solution. I simply added a cron job that periodically runs the following command:

`find /tmp/*tmp -amin +10 -exec rm -f {} \;`

Basically, `find` locates all of JetS3t's tmp files that were accessed at least ten minutes ago (thanks to `-atime +10`) and then deletes them.

This mimics the behavior of `tmpreaper` or `tmpwatch` present on some systems. For others using these apps, beware, as they can facilitate some [setuid exploits.](http://pwet.fr/man/linux/administration_systeme/tmpreaper) I realize my approach may also be susceptible to the same exploits, but for now I have no choice.

Comment: FWIW, I would still love to hear suggestions. :)

Comment: Remember that lots of file systems are mounted with the `noatime` flag which disables atimes to reduce the load (since atimes require writes even when you are just reading things). If it works for you you most likely do have atimes enabled but in case you ever change to a different system they might be disabled by default.